# how to generate the graph in wireshark?

Tags: linux, wireshark

```
$ sudo tshark -i eth0 -R 'http.request.method == "GET"' "port 80"
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
  5.641015   10.53.0.66 -> 209.85.143.104 HTTP GET / HTTP/1.1
```

I want to get number of bytes against each HTTP request. Can you help me to do that.
In my analysis, i have different number of HTTP request (may be four different type of HTTP request) and i want to plot a graph of traffic (number of bytes) against each HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the wireshark GUI utility versus the tshark command line tool.

You can separate this into two steps, if you like, with the `-w` option to tshark.  Then copy the file to your full-UI environment and open it with the wireshark utility.

Perhaps this is what you want:

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatIOGraphs.html

It will depend on how you can write filters to separate out your HTTP requests by type.